# For some reason I get a compiler error with this code

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have checked several times, my method is outside of my main method and yet it still gives me an "Illegal Start of Expression" error. I have been coding for a while and this just doesn't make sense. Perhaps a fresh set of eyes will do me some good. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
@author David Jacobsen
@version 10/10/2013
*/
public class basicMenu {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Top Menu Choice Printer
    System.out.println("1. Let's make a Deal");
    System.out.println("2. Conversion Calculator");
    System.out.println("3. Statistical Analysis");
    System.out.println(" ");
    //Choose 1, 2, or 3 Menu Input
    double doubleA;
    Scanner topMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please select and option, 1 - 3:");
    doubleA = topMenu.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Good choice.");
    //Method Chooser
    //Menu Choice "Let's make a Deal!"
    if (doubleA <= 1) {
      basicMenu.letsMakeADeal();
    }
/*    //Menu Choice "Statistical Analysis"
    else if (doubleA >= 3) {
      basicMenu.statisticalAnalysis();
    }
    //Menu Choice "Conversion Calculator"
    else {
      basicMenu.conversionCalculator();
    }
  } */
  //Let's make a Deal Method
  public static Boolean letsMakeADeal() {
    //Let's make a Deal Choice Printer
    System.out.println("1. Door Number One");
    System.out.println("2. Door Number Two");
    System.out.println("3. Door Number Three");
    System.out.println(" ");
    //Choose 1, 2, or 3 Menu Input
    double doubleA;
    Scanner topMenu = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please select a Door, 1 - 3:");
    doubleA = topMenu.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Good choice. Now let's see if you've won yourself a brand new car!");
    boolean didYouWin;
    if (doubleA <= 1) {
      didYouWin = false;
    }
    else if (doubleA >= 3) {
      didYouWin = false;
    }
    else {
      didYouWin = true;
    }
    return didYouWin;
  }
  /*
  //Conversion calculator Method
  public static double conversionCalculator() {

  }

  //Statistical Analysis Method
  public static double statisticalAnalysis() {

  }
  */
}
```

Comment: The last brace before the `letsMakeADeal()` definition should not be commented out.

Comment: You're missing the closing brace to your first main method.

Comment: Your comment block includes the end of the main() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your main might be missing a `}`?

Comment: Really just needed to grab some lunch and look at it again. Thanks for the help guys. I put my comment to the right of my main method closing "}" and it goofed all my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*    //Menu Choice "Statistical Analysis"
    else if (doubleA >= 3) {
      basicMenu.statisticalAnalysis();
    }
    //Menu Choice "Conversion Calculator"
    else {
      basicMenu.conversionCalculator();
    }
  } */
```

Should be

```
/*   //Menu Choice "Statistical Analysis"
    else if (doubleA >= 3) {
      basicMenu.statisticalAnalysis();
    }
    //Menu Choice "Conversion Calculator"
    else {
      basicMenu.conversionCalculator();
    }*/
  }
```

You've misplaced the `*/`